# ng serve, ng build, ng build --prod issues

Tags: angular, forms, ngmodel

So ng serve and ng build compile and run with no errors. When I run ng build prod it gives me the Property 'title' does not exist on type '{}'.  I have tired implementing an interface as well and get the same errors. The code runs perfectly fine with no errors with ng serve.

```
`<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input #title="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="recipe.title" name="title" id="title" type="text" class="form-control" required>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="title.touched && title.invalid">
          Title is required
        </div>
      </div>`
```

Here is the Ts file snippet

```
export class RecipeFormComponent {
  categories$: Observable<any>;
  recipe = {};
  id;

  form = new FormGroup({
    ingredients: new FormArray([])
  });

  constructor(
    private categoryService: CategoryService, 
    private recipeService: RecipeService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {

    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if(this.id) this.recipeService.get(this.id).take(1).subscribe(r => this.recipe = r);
   }
```

Comment: Does declaring `recipe` as `recipe: any = {};` help?

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. been stuck on this issue forever.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is looking for title on recipe, but they don't exist on the Object class. You need to declare the type of your objects as any and then Typescript won't complain about your property names. Like this:

**`recipe: any = {};`**